# Windows Phone 7 Webbrowser content rendered event

Tags: windows-phone-7, event-handling, browser

I'm looking for a way to tell when content in a Webbrowser control has first been rendered to the screen in Windows Phone 7. I was able to do this in Android by adding a custom PictureListener to the WebView, but I'm not able to find anything similar in WP7. I tried hooking into Loaded, LoadCompleted, and LayoutUpdated just to see if any of these would help me but sadly they did not.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

What I have is basically a pop up and brings up a web browser, and I want to show a loading dialog that spins until there is something for the user to see, and then close the dialog after that. I could have it sit there until the whole page loads, but I fear that would annoy people. But, on the other side of the coin, I also don't want the user to just look at a blank white screen if the page is taking a long time to load; there needs to be some indication that something is going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigated%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event?

> **WebBrowser.Navigated Event**
>   Occurs after the WebBrowser control successfully navigates.

Comment: I assume that event is fired when the browser hits a page, but I specifically need to know when something is visible from that page on the screen. I suppose it would help if I explained the why behind this. I'll update the question.

Comment: Ok. Another question: are you able to edit the web page? Because in that case, you could use the ScriptNotify technique by calling window.external.notify() in the document.ready event of the HTML page.

Comment: Interesting... my knowledge of web programming is scant, so I'll have to dig a bit. Thanks for the idea, I'll report back here when I reach some kind of conclusion as to whether this could work or not.